# Django Template login.html does not exist Okta Auth

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I've been trying to implement [Okta Auth](https://pypi.org/project/django-okta-auth/) for authentication on my Django web application. Currently I am running into the following error: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: okta_oauth2/login.html`.

Here are the relevant settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("okta_oauth2.backend.OktaBackend",)

OKTA_AUTH = {
    "ORG_URL": "https://{org}.okta.com/",
    "ISSUER": "https://{org}.okta.com/oauth2/default",
    "CLIENT_ID": os.getenv('okta_client_id'),
    "CLIENT_SECRET": os.getenv('okta_secret_id'),
    "SCOPES": "openid profile email offline_access", # this is the default and can be omitted
    "REDIRECT_URI": "http://localhost:8000/accounts/oauth2/callback",
    "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL": "/", # default
    "CACHE_PREFIX": "okta", # default
    "CACHE_ALIAS": "default", # default
    "PUBLIC_NAMED_URLS": (), # default
    "PUBLIC_URLS": (), # default
    "USE_USERNAME": False, # default
}
....
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Directory structure:

root -- > app1 --> templates --> app1 --> *several HTML files* (django is able to find these templates).

root -- > okta_oath2 --> templates -- > okta_oath2 --> login.html

I have tried placing the login.html in several different places but can't seem to figure out where it should go. The debug log keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: Assuming `app1` is the primary app in your project, then you need to put it in `app1/templates/okta_oauth2/login.html`.

Comment: I did exactly that but no luck unfortunately.  Does the okta_oauth2 package perhaps overwrite this template finding logic of Django and look for it somewhere completely different?

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace for the error? it will show you all the template paths that Django looked in.

Comment: My bad here, made a type in the name of the directory... Thanks for responding